# Spark SQL rlike to find all strings with trailing numbers

Tags: sql, regex, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While querying from data frame I have tried to use `rlike` without much success.

Sample data:

```
column_a|column_b
1|abc xyz
2|123 abc xyz
3|abc 123 xyz
4|abc 123
5|xyz 123
```

Expected output:

```
column_a|column_b
4|abc 123
5|xyz 123
```

I have tried:

```sql
select * from table_1 where column_b rlike '\d+$' (select * from table_1 where column_b rlike '/\d+$')
```

Output (no results):

```
column_a|column_b
```

I've also tried:

```sql
select * from table_1 where column_b rlike '\d*$' (select * from table_1 where column_b rlike '/\d*$')
```

Output (all rows):

```
column_a|column_b
1|abc xyz
2|123 abc xyz
3|abc 123 xyz
4|abc 123
5|xyz 123
```

Is my regex incorrect? I have tested using python and online tester and it looks correct. Or does `rlike` support some specific regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a bit more escaping to make it work. In particular:

```
spark.sql("SELECT 'abc 123' RLIKE '\\\\d+$'").show()
```

```
+------------------+
|abc 123 RLIKE \d+$|
+------------------+
|              true|
+------------------+
```

```py
spark.sql("SELECT '123 abc xyz' RLIKE '\\\\d+$'").show()
```

```
+----------------------+
|123 abc xyz RLIKE \d+$|
+----------------------+
|                 false|
+----------------------+
```

Comment: What the f... Can you please explain why so many escapes are needed? I mean it works, but I'd like to understand which layer does what :)

Comment: @LauriK You call this many? What about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52149872/6910411)? The problem is twofold - the expression is evaluated on JVM so if you wanted to call it directly in Java you'd already need `"\\d+$'`. And since our string has to be passed to the other side, each backlash has to be escaped as well.