# How to remove '\' from a string in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, text, sparklyr

I am using `sparklyr` and have a spark dataframe with a column `word`that contains words, some of which contain special characters which I want to remove. I was succesful in using `regepx_replace` and `\\\\` before special characters, just like this:

```
words.sdf <- words.sdf %>% 
  mutate(word = regexp_replace(word, '\\\\(', '')) %>% 
  mutate(word = regexp_replace(word, '\\\\)', '')) %>% 
  mutate(word = regexp_replace(word, '\\\\+', '')) %>% 
  mutate(word = regexp_replace(word, '\\\\?', '')) %>%
  mutate(word = regexp_replace(word, '\\\\:', '')) %>%
  mutate(word = regexp_replace(word, '\\\\;', '')) %>%
  mutate(word = regexp_replace(word, '\\\\!', ''))
```

Now I want to remove `\`. I have tried both :

```
words.sdf <- words.sdf %>% 
  mutate(word = regexp_replace(word, '\\\\\', ''))
```

and :

```
words.sdf <- words.sdf %>% 
  mutate(word = regexp_replace(word, '\', ''))
```

But neither will work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to correct your code for both R-side and Java side escaping so what you need is actually `"\\\\\\\\"`:

```
df <- copy_to(sc, tibble(word = "(abc\\zyx: 1)"))

df %>% mutate(regexp_replace(word, "\\\\\\\\", ""))
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# Database: spark_shell_connection
  word           `regexp_replace(word, "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\", "")`
  <chr>          <chr>                                         
1 "(abc\\zyx:1)" (abczyx: 1)
```

Depending on your exact requirement it might be easier to match all characters at once. You could for example preserve only word characters (`\w`) and whitespaces (`\s`):

```
df %>% mutate(regexp_replace(word, "[^\\\\w+\\\\s+]", ""))
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# Database: spark_shell_connection
  word            `regexp_replace(word, "[^\\\\\\\\w+\\\\\\\\s+]", "")`
  <chr>           <chr>                                                
1 "(abc\\zyx: 1)" abczyx 1
```

or word characters only

```
df %>% mutate(regexp_replace(word, "[^\\\\w+]", ""))
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# Database: spark_shell_connection
  word            `regexp_replace(word, "[^\\\\\\\\w+]", "")`
  <chr>           <chr>                                      
1 "(abc\\zyx: 1)" abczyx1
```

Comment: So for replacing // we need ////////? I need to remove ]. What do I need to write for this?